# How to make contextBridge work even if contextisolation is turned off

Tags: javascript, electron

I some of my code requires `contextIsolation` turned on and my preload.js looks like this:

```js
const { contextBridge } = require("electron");
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron/renderer");

const API = {
    window: {
        close: () => ipcRenderer.send("app/close"),
        minimize: () => ipcRenderer.send("app/minimize"),
    }
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("app", API);
```

and everytime I launch the app it sends this error:

```
Uncaught Error: contextBridge API can only be used when contextIsolation is enabled
    at node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:45:277
    at Object.exposeInMainWorld (node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:45:359)
    at preload.js:11:15
```

Edit: Here is the script that is supposed to be interacting with the preload script:

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron/renderer");
const MINUS = document.getElementById("minimizeApp");
const CLOSE = document.getElementById("closeApp");

MINUS.addEventListener("click", minimizeApp);
CLOSE.addEventListener("click", closeApp);

function closeApp() {
    app.window.close();
}
function minimizeApp() {
    app.window.minimize();
}
```

this is imported via the `<script>` tag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The point of that API is to bridge a gap between otherwise two completely isolated places. If you're not isolating them you have no reason to use it hence the error message.

**With context isolation**

As the preload script will be executed in a different context, you need the Context Bridge API to expose your API to the renderer process:

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('MY_API', {
  getAnswer() {
    return 42;
  }
});
```

**Without context isolation**

Both the preload script and the renderer process share the same context. So in the preload script you can simply attach your API directly to the `window` object. That `window` will be the same as the one in the renderer process:

```js
// preload script
window.MY_API = {
  getAnswer() {
    return 42;
  }
}
```

i.e. no need to use the Context Bridge API here ;)

In any case `MY_API` is available from the `window` object in your renderer process:

```html
<!-- renderer process -->
<body>
  <script>
    alert(window.MY_API.getAnswer());
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Then how do I connect them together?

Comment: @CodeSearcher See update.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work

Comment: The error shows as: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close') at index.html:15:24`

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs of electron. Turning contextIsolation off is a no-no for newer versions of electron. What you actually want is to expose MY_API through contextBridge and setup an ipcRenderer to signal processes back and forth.

Comment: But part of my code doesn't work if I turn it off.

Comment: It's not supposed to be turned off. contextIsolation became "mandatory" let's put it in a way because turning it off is a major security risk.

Comment: You said that some of your code requires contextIsolation but you get an error: contextBridge API can only be used when contextIsolation is enabled. This means its off

Comment: What? contextIsolation is turned enabled which causes contextBridge API to break.

Comment: contextBridge API can only be used when contextIsolation is enabled. that's the error you get. If you had contextIsolation enabled then why contextBridge wouldn't work?

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now. but now I have a different problem